# Android MediaRecorder is not generating a streamable AAC-LC audio using AudioEncoder.AAC

Tags: android, audio-streaming, audio-recording, codec, mediarecorder

I am using a Nexus 7 with Android version 4.2+. So according to the [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core) all listed encoders and container formats are supported.

Now I want to record an audio using the [AAC-LC encoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.html#AAC) and the [MPEG-4 container format](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html#MPEG_4) (file type).

In the generated file, when I open it in an HEX-Editor, I see that the file is an [ISO Base Media file](http://jaadec.sourceforge.net/specs/ISO_14496-12_ISOBMFF.pdf) having the `isom` File Type Box (Section 4.3) with the following compatible brands: `isom` and `3gp4`. The remaining of the file is mostly an `mdat` Box (containing the actual audio data). The following HEX snippet from the beginning of the file was telling me this:

```
00000018 66747970 69736F6D 00000000 69736F6D 33677034 00029708 6D646174 ...
```

translated as:

```
      24 ftyp     isom     no-minor isom     3gp4     0x29708  mdat     ...
```

which means:

the file (`ftyp`) is complying with the ISO/IEC 14496-12 (`isom`) and specifies no minor version. The compatible brands with this file are: `isom` and `3gp4`. Then follows the audio data box (mdat) with length `0x29708`

Where is the part telling me that this is an AAC-LC (AAC Low complexity) encoded file?

Moreover, compared to other AAC-LC files on the [web](http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/http-aac.htm) their header (file box) is different mentioning `mp42` as `ftyp` and `mp42`, `isom`, `ndia` as compatible brands. Such a file is also streamable (how AAC-LC should be).

But the Android generated AAC_LC (MP4) file is NOT streamable. So what is Android MediaRecorder or me doing wrong? I am using the following code:

```
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
// the bit rate should be adjusted silently if out of range
mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(320000);
mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(48000);
```

Comment: I have also tested with the HE-AAC encoder. The same story: Android MediaRecorder generates the same `isom` and `3gp4` compatible brands. I see no trace telling me that the file is encoded with HE-AAC.

Comment: Horrible Nexus7 donot supports all the listed encoding schemes and so does many other devices.